# setting the http header in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to modify my http request header to add an Authorization. the problem is the modification is ignored. this is my angular 2 code :

```
let headers = new Headers({
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.authenticationService.getToken()
});

return this.http.get('myURL',{ headers: headers }).map((res : Response) => <myobject[]>res.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your token before creating the Headers object. Also, in TypeScript/ES6 you can use template strings `` instead of concatenating strings.

```
const token = this.authenticationService.getToken();

let headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
});
```

Comment: Does getToken() return data asynchronously? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: thanks for replying Stephen. well the result is displayed in the function when i do Console.log so the data is present. The Problem is that the modification are not setted in the header even the content-type. I'im using JWT for authentication. only 401 error for the response because the jwt filter see a null token